# python exception handling with raise but why runtimeerror is needed

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to understand this piece of code from a Python book.

```
def client(hostname, port):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.connect((hostname, port))
    print('Client socket name is {}'.format(sock.getsockname()))

    delay = 0.1  # seconds
    text = 'This is another message'
    data = text.encode('ascii')
    while True:
        sock.send(data)
        print('Waiting up to {} seconds for a reply'.format(delay))
        sock.settimeout(delay)
        try:
            data = sock.recv(MAX_BYTES)
        except socket.timeout as exc:
            delay *= 2  # wait even longer for the next request
            if delay > 2.0:
                raise RuntimeError('I think the server is down') from exc
        else:
            break   # we are done, and can stop looping

    print('The server says {!r}'.format(data.decode('ascii')))
```

In this line:

```
raise RuntimeError('I think the server is down') from exc
```

I know "raise" can raise an exception and "exc" includes the exception. But I don't understand why we need "RuntimeError('I think the server is down')". What is the point of having this line our code as opposed to just having a "raise" statement only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In short:**

The output of the two are different:

```
raise
```

Gives this output:

```
RuntimeError: No active exception to reraise #or whatever exception is active
```

Whereas:

```
raise RuntimeError('I think the server is down')
```

Gives:

```
RuntimeError: I think the server is down
```

In the latter you are specifying a runtime error where as the first you are just running the error from the exception.

**Additional example:**

For further explanation consider the following example:

```
try:
    9/0
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    raise
```

Gives the output:

```
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Whereas:

```
try:
    9/0
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    raise RuntimeError('I think the server is down') from e
```

This code give the output:

```
RuntimeError: I think the server is down
```

So this is a way to avoid one error and instead raise a different error.

**Why this may be desired:**

Imagine you have a program that searches for texts files and divides some number by the number of text files that it finds. If it does not find a file it will try: `some_number/num_files` which is `some_number/0` and it will give `ZeroDivisionError`. In this case you may want to instead `raise FileNotFoundError`. In which case you could use: `raise FileNotFoundError('There are no text files in the specified folder.')`.

Comment: Since its done in an exception handler where there is an active exception, `raise` would reraise the `socket.timeout` error.

Comment: @tdelaney I am aware, and?

Comment: @tdelaney did you not think my explanation covered that? The additional example I gave exemplifies exactly that.

Comment: You claim that a naked `raise` results in `RuntimeError: No active exception to reraise #or whatever exception is active`. If you are aware that is not true, then why put it in your answer?

Comment: that is true though

Comment: especially the part that says "or whatever exception is active"

Comment: Although it is besides the point, I would also argue that a "naked" raise would be one with no other surrounding code and thus one that would not have an active exception.

Comment: No, it doesn't. OP asks about a raise specifically in the context of an exception handler. The fact that a raise outside of an exception handler does something different is totally irrelevant. Why put it in at all? And why make it the lead with no mention that you are talking about a completely different context than the questioner asked?

Comment: LOL - I guess we could change "naked raise" to "raise with no expression present". That would be way more clear.

Comment: Do you not agree that `raise` will give `RuntimeError: No active exception to reraise #or whatever exception is active` especially the part `#or whatever exception is active`? If not, then it is not worth discussing because this is definitely the case and your ignorance would hinder any productivity. If so, then do you not think the following explanation describes anything he may not have assumed in the first, pretty clear, example?

Comment: The real reason I gave a general example first is for future readers who may not have the exact exception as the OP. In that case a simple explanation of the general behavior would suffice. Then, if further, more specific examples were needed by either the OP or future readers they could read on.

Comment: You funny xD a `raise`, regardless of context, outputs either `No active exception to reraise` (default you may could say)` or instead `*whatever exception is active*` exactly as I describe.

Comment: "in short: the output is different" answers why, and gives a non-specific example of `raise`. Makes sense, right? It's a short version, simplified you could say. "Further example" gives a general example, but with specifics, in case it helps someone better understand the behavior. "why this could be desired" is a detailed response directly to the question using yet another example that allows people to understand in more detail. I don't understand why you are struggling so much with this. It's simple really.

Comment: And, although you probably won't believe me, I was the one who downvoted your answer, but I actually didn't even know that it was you when I did it. I just found the answer to be verbose and hard to read/follow. Also the lack of any examples seems to take away from the effectiveness. Therefore, in my opinion it was not very useful. I would take away the downvote if I could, just for you, but too much time has passed so I am not allowed.

Comment: @tdelaney maybe this will clear things up: the "in-short" section aims to answer the question "why write `raise RuntimeError()` when I can write `raise`" and the simple answer is "because the output is different," so anyone else who is looking for "why write `raise **blank**` when I can write `raise`. will see their answer immediately (as well as the OP if that is all he was looking for...) then if that, along with the explanation in that section, is not enough the following examples can help.

Comment: I am truly trying to help you understand the reason I answered in the way I did and why that can be helpful to the OP as well as others. I apologize if my explanations are not sufficient.

Comment: And, I also appreciate your efforts in attempting to help my answer be the best that it can be.

Comment: Yet the problem remains. The question is _...as opposed to just having a "raise" statement only._ If you do a `raise` in an exception handler, it reraises the current exception. You could change the start of your answer where you claim it raises `RuntimeError: No active exception to reraise` to simply be a reraise of `socket.timeout`. You added details to your answer but that's after I wrote the comment and answered the question. Just change that first bit so that others reading this answer don't get the wrong information.

Answer (score 0):

`socket.timeout` is a subclass of `OSError`. For whatever reason, the author of this code wants `client` to raise a `RuntimeError` instead in this case.

Comment: That's not quite what the OP was asking.

Answer (score -1):

This is a common practice. A package may handle a bunch of different types of errors deep in the bowels of its code. But how relevant are the execptions to the user of the module - especially when the package itself may change over time? It makes sense to aggregate these exceptions into a smaller, documented set of exceptions. Instead of a user needing to catch and figure out how to process dozens of exceptions whose meaning isn't very clear, the package can do the grunt work and pass back a more friendly set of errors.

Suppose this package had several different ways of getting this data from the server, or there were several different ways a downed server can be detected. The user doesn't care if its a timeout in this bit of code or perhaps it was detected in some other way. One could imagine middleware that is handing out server addresses realizes there is none available. The "bug" in this code is that the detailed error is not logged so there is no good way for anyone to figure out what happened.

This is all just speculation of course. I presume that in context of the book you are reading it makes sense. This is demo code showing a common practice of aggregating exceptions.